# make start of week as monday or sunday influxdb

Tags: influxdb

I am using influx db 1.0.2 version. when I query to get aggregate of 1 week. week of day starts from Thursday instead of monday/sunday.

```
SELECT SUM(value) FROM measurement_name WHERE time >= '2016-10-09T18:30:00Z' AND time < '2016-11-07T18:29:59Z' GROUP BY time(1w)
```

How it can be configured?

Answer (score 3):

this ugly bug can be fixed by adding offset into grouping by time.

```
 SELECT SUM(value) FROM measurement_name WHERE time >= '2016-10-09T18:30:00Z' AND time < '2016-11-07T18:29:59Z' GROUP BY time(1w, 4d)
```

for more information, [click here](http://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.0/query_language/data_exploration/#advanced-group-by-time-syntax)